# Generic Binary Search - JAVA -

Tags: java, generics, binary-search, comparable

I dont know if the functionality of my code is the correct one for binary search BUT this is not my question, I want to solve it myself.

My problem is in testing its functionality while I get the following errors:

[image]
[image]

I really dont know how to solve this issue. Please help me!

My code:

```
public class BinarySearchGeneric<T extends Comparable<T>>{

public int search(T[] array, T element){
    int start = 0;
    int end = array.length - 1;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    while(!element.equals(array[mid]) && end != 0) {
        if (element.equals(array[mid])) {
            return mid;
        } else if (array[mid].compareTo(element) < 0) {
            end = mid - 1;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
        } else if(array[mid].compareTo(element) > 0){
            start = mid + 1;
            mid = (start + end) / 2;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Main Method:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    BinarySearchGeneric binarySearchGeneric = new BinarySearchGeneric(a);
    System.out.println("BinarySearch Generic: " + binarySearchGeneric.search(a, 8));

    }
}
```

Comment: Not the issue, but consider that generics and arrays are not friendly bedfellows. Consider searching a `List<T>` rather than a `T[]`.

Comment: You can't have generics with primitive types. Use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

Comment: Also: don't use raw types: `BinarySearchGeneric<Integer>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner You're right, but that wasn't the immediate cause of error.

Comment: Also: `equals` is not necessarily implemented consistently with `compare`: you should use `array[mid].compareTo(element) == 0` rather than `equals` (and you can just calculate `array[mid].compareTo(element)` once and put it in a variable).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen aha, yes. Unhammered.

Comment: @AndyTurner Too late for me...already postee my answer for someone else :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can always roll back their answer and post again. You were pretty generous in editing such a poor-quality answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks! You took me to the right solution! :)

Comment: @AndyTurner I try to upvote your answer but I cant find any button :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two compilation issues here:

1. There is no constructor of `BinarySearchGeneric` which takes a parameter, but you're trying to pass the parameter. Remove it:

   ```
   BinarySearchGeneric binarySearchGeneric = new BinarySearchGeneric();
   ```
2. `int[]` is not an acceptable parameter to a generic method expecting an array, because `int` is a primitive type, not a reference type, and so can't be used in generics. The solution is simply to declare an array of `Integer`, rather than `int`:

   ```
   Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   ```

   The compiler converts these int literals to `Integer` instances automatically.

---

But there are more issues.

- You're declaring a variable of [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). This basically switches off the compiler's type checking associated with that variable, making it likely that you will make a type error. Add the generic parameters:

  ```
  BinarySearchGeneric<Integer> binarySearchGeneric = new BinarySearchGeneric<>();
  ```
- Arrays and generics don't really play well together. Things would start get a bit messy if you declared a generic, comparable class:

  ```
  class GenericComparable<T> extends Comparable<T> { ... }
  ```

  and then tried to declare an array of `GenericComparable`s to pass to `binarySearchGeneric`, since you can't directly create a generic array.

  It's much easier simply to avoid arrays, and use a `List<T>` instead:

  ```
  public int search(List<T> array, T element){
  ```
- Potentially, you have inconsistent behaviour, because you are mixing `equals` and `compareTo` in the search. Whilst `compareTo` should be consistent with `equals` (in the sense that `a.compareTo(b) <=> a.equals(b)`, it isn't necessarily true.

  You can make the behaviour consistent by only using `compareTo`:

  ```
  int c = array[mid].compareTo(element);
  if (c == 0) {
    // ...
  } else if (c < 0) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a user defined constructor for the `BinarySearchGeneric` class, so your code should look something like this:

```
BinarySearchGeneric binarySearchGeneric = new BinarySearchGeneric();
System.out.println("BinarySearch Genetic: ", binarySearchGeneric(a, 8));
```

Comment: Ah damn, thanks, I had a constructor before and hadnt changed it. Now I did, but the 2nd error is still there..

Comment: @JavaMan the second error is fixed by using `Integer[]`.